# Spring boot: mockMvc testing controller: Expected: Entity, Actuall: null

Tags: spring-boot, junit, mockito, mockmvc

How looks my json:

```
event object
{
  ...
  "game": {
      //game fields
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

I am trying to do:

```
event.setGame(new Game());
```

And check if there is my value by mockMvc

```
.andExpect(jsonPath("$.game").value(event.getGame()))
```

But i am getting error:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: JSON path "$.game" 
Expected : Event(id= null, name= null, ...)
Actual   :null
```

Why i am getting null, if i should get just empty game?

**P.S.** even if i set fields to game, i will get null

I make .andDo(print), and get :

```
 Body =  // event
{
    "id":"5f087eec-8bf0-11eb-8dcd-0242ac130003",
    "game":
        {
        "id":null,
        "team1":null,
        "team2":null,
        "gameDate":null,
        },
    "user":
        {
        //user fields
        }
}
```

How looks controller:

```
@GetMapping("/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<GetEventById> getEventById @PathVariable("id") String id) {
        GetEventByIResponse dto= service.getEventById(id);
        return ResponseEntity
                .status(HttpStatus.OK)
                .body(dto);
    }
```

In my test i am creating GetEventByIResponse, how it looks:

```
public class Event {
    private String id;
    private Game game;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Could you please post your entire controller class?

Comment: @Satoshi Could you please also post the Game and the GetUserByIdDTO class. Note that your AssertionError expects an Event, but you are working with a Game object. Is there some inheritance? This my disturb JSON deserialization.

Comment: @oliver_t quetion updated

Answer (score 0):

The JsonPath assert works as follows:

1. It first parses the path result into a Map/List/Object, to see if the origin was an array/object/simple type.
2. Then, if it's a Map (like in your case) it tries to parse the path result into the same type as the expected object.
3. Finally it compare the created object to the expected object using equals().

In your case I see several problems:

- The AssertionError talks about an Event although you seem to hand in a Game.
- We do not know if the serialization/deserialization works at all

Maybe you should try one of the following:

1. Place a breakpoint [right here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/e4a5d2aaa59266b294e155c4fd80b9ef3e852330/spring-test/src/main/java/org/springframework/test/util/JsonPathExpectationsHelper.java#L99) to watch the assert steps in your debugger:
2. Start with simple type comparisons:

```java
.andExpect(jsonPath("$.id").value("foo"))
.andExpect(jsonPath("$.game.id").value("bar"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the json path referencing the game child object is incorrect, try below:

```
.andExpect(jsonPath("$.event.game").value(event.getGame()))
```